# NSIS SQL connection

Tags: sql-server, deployment, nsis

While installing with my NSIS installer script I need to run some script on SQL Server: select, update, create and insert.

How can I do that without having a SQL Server engine on the computer running the NSIS installer?

I thought about packing a SQL Server Compact Edition to my installer in order to use it to connect to the SQL Server. Is that the way I should go for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a Plugin for NSIS that can connect to a MS SQL database: [MSSQL_OLEDB_plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/MSSQL_OLEDB_plug-in)

It can be used like that:

```
${OLEDB}::SQL_Logon    "$SQLSERVER" "$SQLUSER" "$SQLPASSWORD"
${OLEDB}::SQL_Execute  "$SQLQUERY"
${OLEDB}::SQL_GetError
${OLEDB}::SQL_GetRow
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0
${OLEDB}::SQL_Logout
```

Comment: When you are banned from asking questions then you should read [what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-question-2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) carefully.

Comment: I need to write the log in text file for the geterror function i used  `${LogText} Pop $0 DetailPrint $0` it is not working in `${OLEDB}::SQL_ExecuteScript $SQLFILE` while executing the whole sqlfile

Comment: Then ask a new question about it with a detailed description of your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060462/nsis-write-log-on-sql-query-file-execute-on-sql-error   suggest me for logging the unexecuted query in sql file

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the SQL Server engine to perform queries on a remote machine, you need a driver.

One approach is to use the command line client, which also requires the native driver. You probably want to bundle or search for the driver your application uses in your installer.

In SQL Server 2005 or later the command line client is called [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). It can be downloaded from the feature pack download pages ([2005](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24793)|[2008](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6375)|[2008R2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16978)|[2012](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29065)).

So its simply a matter of bundling a SQL script with the installer and executing the script by calling sqlcmd with [ExecWait](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.4).

You can run a script using a trusted connection via:

```
sqlcmd -S _SERVER\_INSTANCE_ -d _DBNAME_ -i _SCRIPT_FILE_
```

Or with a SQL Login:

```
sqlcmd -S _SERVER\_INSTANCE_ -d _DBNAME_ -U _USERNAME_ -P _PASSWORD_ -i _SCRIPT_FILE_
```

A SQL 2000 version of this approach can be found [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Execute_SQL_Server_scripts) on the [nsis wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net).